# How to create magento helper class?

Tags: php, magento

I have the following magento helper class.

```
class CommissionJunction extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data
{

    /**
     * Get SKU, quantity, price and discount amount for each product in a given order
     * @param object $order
     * @return array
     */
    private function _getOrderProductsList($order) {
        $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
        $purchasedSkus = array();
        $count_orderItems = count($orderItems);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count_orderItems; $i++) {
            $purchasedSkus[$i] = array(
              'ITEM' => $orderItems[$i]['sku'],
                'QTY' => number_format($orderItems[$i]['qty_ordered'],0), // no decimals
                'AMT' => number_format($orderItems[$i]['price'],2) // 2 decimal places
                'DCNT' => number_format(abs($orderItems[$i]['discount_amount']),2) */
            );
        }
        return $purchasedSkus;
    }

    /**
     * Get the Universal Data (JSON) Object for Commission Junction.
     * This object contains the order details passed on to Commission Junction for reporting purposes
     * on the Checkout Success / Order Confirmation page.
     * Notes:
     *  - CID, TYPE AND CURRENCY are hard coded
     * @param string $orderId
     * @return JSON object Universal Data Object for Commission Junction $json_masterTmsUdp
     */
    public function getCommissionJunctionUdo($orderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
        $udo = array();
        $udo['CID'] = 'XXXX';
        $udo['TYPE'] = 'XXXX';
        $udo['CURRENCY'] = 'USD';
        $udo['OID'] = $orderId;
        $udo['DISCOUNT'] = number_format(abs($order->discount_amount),2);

        $order_coupon_code = $order->coupon_code;
        if(!is_null($order_coupon_code) && !empty($order_coupon_code)) {
            $udo['COUPON'] = $order_coupon_code;
        }

        $udo['PRODUCTLIST'] = self::_getOrderProductsList($order);       

        if(Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('aff_commissionjunction') == 'cjafflx') {
            $udo['FIRECJ'] = "TRUE";
        }
        else {
            $udo['FIRECJ'] = "FALSE";
        }

        $masterTmsUdo['CJ'] = $udo;
        $json_masterTmsUdo = json_encode($masterTmsUdo);

        return $json_masterTmsUdo;

    }       


}
```

And I found this site where they explain how to register a helper class

http://codegento.com/2011/02/creating-a-helper-class/

The only thing I dont know its:

1. Where in the magento structure should I add this php class?
2. Where is the config.xml I should edit?

Comment: I've put mine under `app/code/community`. Another issue, you should use the same naming convention for your class as Magento uses i.e. `ComissionJunction_Helper_Data` Alse the config XML should be placed in your `app/code/community/ComissionJunction/etc`folder

Comment: Community is for third party classes, like those you create. I don't think core should be empty though? That's  where the main classes resides.

Comment: lol no, it was a glitch on my IDE, neither are empty, thanks

Comment: please post that as an answer to get the points and maybe in the meantime you can help me with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223346/warning-include-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory-in-magento-hel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User created classes should be placed in this folder:

```
app/code/community
```

Another issue, you should use the same naming convention for your class as Magento uses i.e.

```
MOduleNameSpace_ComissionJunction_Helper_Data
```

Also the config XML should be placed in your `app/code/community/ MOduleNameSpace/ComissionJunction/etc` folder