# Warning: include failed to open stream: No such file or directory in magento helper

Tags: php, magento, php-5.3

I have created the following config.xml file:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <awesome>
                <class>CommissionJunction</class>
            </awesome>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

I have added the following php file: as Data.php

```
<?php
    class CommissionJunction extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data
    {

        /**
        * Get SKU, quantity, price and discount amount for each product in a given order
        * @param object $order
        * @return array
        */
        private function _getOrderProductsList($order)
        {
            $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
            $purchasedSkus = array();
            $count_orderItems = count($orderItems);
            for($i = 0; $i < $count_orderItems; $i++) {
                $purchasedSkus[$i] = array(
                    'ITEM' => $orderItems[$i]['sku'],
                    'QTY' => number_format($orderItems[$i]['qty_ordered'],0), // no decimals
                    'AMT' => number_format($orderItems[$i]['price'],2), // 2 decimal places
                    'DCNT' => number_format(abs($orderItems[$i]['discount_amount']),2)
                 );
            }

            return $purchasedSkus;
        }

        /**
        * Get the Universal Data (JSON) Object for Commission Junction.
        * This object contains the order details passed on to Commission Junction for reporting purposes
        * on the Checkout Success / Order Confirmation page.
        * Notes:
        *  - CID, TYPE AND CURRENCY are hard coded
        * @param string $orderId
        * @return JSON object Universal Data Object for Commission Junction $json_masterTmsUdp
        */
        public function getCommissionJunctionUdo($orderId)
        {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
            $udo = array();
            $udo['CID'] = 'XXXX';
            $udo['TYPE'] = 'XXXX';
            $udo['CURRENCY'] = 'USD';
            $udo['OID'] = $orderId;
            $udo['DISCOUNT'] = number_format(abs($order->discount_amount),2);

            $order_coupon_code = $order->coupon_code;
            if(!is_null($order_coupon_code) && !empty($order_coupon_code))
            {
                $udo['COUPON'] = $order_coupon_code;
            }

            $udo['PRODUCTLIST'] = self::_getOrderProductsList($order);

            if(Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('aff_commissionjunction') == 'cjafflx')
            {
                $udo['FIRECJ'] = "TRUE";
            }
            else
            {
                $udo['FIRECJ'] = "FALSE";
            }

            $masterTmsUdo['CJ'] = $udo;
            $json_masterTmsUdo = json_encode($masterTmsUdo);

            return $json_masterTmsUdo;

        }

    }
```

Then in succes.phtml I added this:

```
<script>var MasterTmsUdo = <?php echo Mage::helper('commissionjunction')->getCommissionJunctionUdo($this->getOrderId()); ?></script>
<script>/*DO NOT ALTER *** tpd*/(function(e){var t="1340",n=document,r,i,s={http:"http://cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js",https:"https://secure-cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js"},o=s[/\w+/.exec(window.location.protocol)[0]];i=n.createElement("script"),i.type="text/javascript",i.async=!0,i.src=o+"#"+t,r=n.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],r.parentNode.insertBefore(i,r),i.readyState?i.onreadystatechange=function(){if(i.readyState==="loaded"||i.readyState==="complete")i.onreadystatechange=null}:i.onload=function(){try{e()}catch(t){}}})(function(){});</script>
```

Errors:
1. My success page is not rendering correctly, the template is lost.
2. I got the following in system.log

```
014-08-09T21:33:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Commissionjunction/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/theprint/public_html/preprod/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-09T21:33:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Commissionjunction/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/theprint/public_html/preprod/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

magento needs class name like `Packagename_Modulename_Helper`

config.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <CommissionJunction>
                <class>CompanyName_CommissionJunction_Helper</class>
            </CommissionJunction>
        </helpers>
   </global>
</config>
```

and in your class head:

```
class CompanyName_CommissionJunction_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
```

then you can call with: `Mage::helper('CommissionJunction');`

Comment: I have changed xml like this: http://screencast.com/t/D3CPLyLI, and I have changed class name to: ThePrinterDepo_CommissionJunction_Helper_Data,  and I didnt change anything on success.phtml, but I still see the same problem on the logs. any idea?

Comment: based on the answer from @Alexei, maybe I have a bad folder structure?

Comment: what happens if you change `ThePrinterDepo_CommissionJunction_Helper_Data` to `ThePrinterDepo_CommissionJunction_Helper`in your config.xml ?

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: @L.V.SharepointArchitect ou sorry i forgotten to say about your folder strucuture :D change to `magento/app/code/local/ThePrinterDepo/CommissionJunction/`

Comment: why local and no community? is there any difference?

Comment: /community/ is reserved for extensions from the [Magento Connect Marketplace](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59024/discussion-between-l-v-sharepoint-architect-and-rcro).

Answer (score 2):

I can see at least 3 mistakes:

1. Your helper class can't be called just `CommissionJunction`. The name must contain all the path starting from namespace of your extension like `Mage_Core_Helper_Data` does. And if your file is called Data.php, then helpr class name must end with Data. So it should look like *Namespace_Extension_Helper_Data*.
2. In config you declare that your helpers should be referenced by string *awesome*, but in template you're trying to get helper by string *commissionjunction*. So you should change it either in config.xml, or in the template.
3. And in config.xml class tag you have to write the path to the helper folder. Something like *Namespace_Extension_Helper*.

Comment: I am a c# developer, so I am not used to this syntax, on Nr 1 how can I get Namespace and Extension?

Comment: If you're creating the helper and you have a config.xml file, then most likely you have created a new extension. Usually it is placed in app/code/local(or community)/Namespace/Extension folder, you just have to use the same values as folder names.

Comment: am I doing a bad folder structre? http://screencast.com/t/D3CPLyLI, please also see answer from the other guy, I did that change

Comment: Yes, folder structure is a little wrong. Create a folder called ThePrinterDepo in community folder. Then move your CommisionJunction folder inside ThePrinterDepo.